# Dictionaries, lists, etc. in Python. How to pull out info in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to pull out the information on the gender of students who are enrolled. My goal is to compare the females and males.

[This is some of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GZgG.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import education
list_of_record = education.get_all_states ()
virginia_education = education.get_state ('Virginia')
enrollment = list_of_record ['enrollment']
```

I tried this but it didn't work. It gives me "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
if enrollment in virginia_education:
    female = enrollment ['gender']
```

Comment: `education.get_all_states()` returns a dictionary of lists, it seems.

Comment: The error seems like a big clue: you're trying to treat something like a dictionary (`somevar['somekey']`) when it is in fact a list.  The traceback should tell you exactly which line is the problem.

Comment: It is good to add more parts of the code, at least you can add here what each function returns, you may also copy and paste the whole error message.